# Python3 numpy with Intel MKL support [Win10]

Tags: python, windows, numpy, conda, intel-mkl

I can see that some of the code that I use could be significantly faster with numpy+mkl support. 
Tested it using conda environment and installing numpy with
`conda install numpy==1.16.5 -c intel` command

Also tried to use numpy+mkl from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) but it's much slower than conda version

My goal is to have a numpy+mkl prebuilt package and all the dependencies available for offline installation not using conda environment. And I hope that performance can be the same.

Pypi repo has intel-numpy==1.15.1 wheel, but it is outdated.

First of all I tried to build numpy using this [guide](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/building-numpyscipy-with-intel-mkl-and-intel-fortran-on-windows) with intel compiler and got weird error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2020.0.166\windows\bin\intel64\icl.exe /c /nologo /O3 /MD /W3 /Qstd=c99 /QxHost /fp:strict /Qopenmp C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2020.0.16\windows\compiler\lib\intel64_win\libiomp5md.lib -Inumpy\core\src\common -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\umath -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -ID:\bin\building_intel\venv\include -IC:\Program Files\Python36\include -IC:\Program Files\Python36\include /Tc_configtest.c /Fo_configtest.obj
xilink /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /MANIFEST _configtest.obj /OUT:_configtest.exe /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:_configtest.exe.manifest
mt.exe -nologo -manifest _configtest.exe.manifest -outputresource:_configtest.exe;1
failure.
removing: _configtest.c _configtest.obj _configtest.obj.d
```

I also checked a few other solutions that could be used to build `*.whl` from conda packages and it didn't work for me. [conda2wheel](https://pypi.org/project/conda2wheel/), [conda-press](https://pypi.org/project/conda-press/)

I know that there is a possibility to use conda build for whl files, but I'm not sure how to use it with already installed packages. (Modifying the recipes in `.conda/pkgs/` directory?)

So the question is how to create numpy+mkl.whl which is that fast as the one that could be installed with conda?

Comment: Have you tried building from the repository using this? https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/building.html#blas

Comment: @Marcel no, but isn't the default pypi numpy already built with openblas?

Comment: There is a newer guide that you might want to look at: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/numpyscipy-with-intel-mkl

Comment: Note that Intel posts the mkl-accelerated packages to the Intel channel on conda cloud. If you can get conda2whl to work, the numpy package can be installed with: `conda install numpy -c intel --no-update-deps`. This [install guide](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-distribution-for-python-with-anaconda) is helpful